# Is there a way to list pull request files(from source branch) with it's location in Azure Devops using APIs? Is there any other way using C#?

Tags: rest, azure-devops, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

My requirement is to read/extract source code of each file present in an Azure DevOps pull request using APIs or C#.
I am able to download the code for a particular file using sample URL below -

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path=/{CodePath}&version={branch name}&api-version=5.1
```

Now I need, list of files with location where it is stored in a branch of Azure DevOps

I have tried different GET calls from REST APIs available.
For example:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/iterations/{iterationId}?api-version=5.1
```

or

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/attachments/{fileName}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

These calls are returning information:

1. About file commits
2. About documents attached in description

Information I have to fulfill the requirement:
Organization name, Repository name, Branch Name, Pull request ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to list pull request files(from source branch) with it's location in Azure Devops using APIs? Is there any other way using C#?

I am afraid there is no such out of way to list pull request files(from source branch) with it's location in Azure Devops using APIs.

First, when we use the pull request API, we could get the `Organization name` and `Pull request ID` directly.

Then we could use the REST API [Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the `repository name` and `sourceRefName` (`Branch Name`):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=5.1
```

[image]

Second, we could use the REST API [Pull Request Commits - Get Pull Request Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20commits/get%20pull%20request%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the commits in the PR:

[image]

Then, we could use the commit id with REST API [Commits - Get Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to file path:

[image]

Now, we get all the info what we want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Drawback of this method is, for multiple commits to a same file, it lists different version of that file.

Answer (score 1):

According to [@Leo Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7460777/leo-liu) answer, this is my code in `powershell` (working great!):

```
      $AzureDevOpsPAT = "$(System.AccessToken)";
      $headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$AzureDevOpsPAT")) }
      $organization = "YOUR ORGANIZATION"
      $project = "YOUR PROJECT"
      $repoId = "YOUR REPOSITORY ID"
      $baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repoId"
      $pullRequest = $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId);

      $commits = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $headers "$baseUrl/pullRequests/$pullRequest/commits" -verbose
      if ($commits.count -gt 0) {                
        foreach ($commit in $commits.value) {                      
              $commitId = $commit.commitId
              $changes = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $headers "$baseUrl/commits/$commitId/changes" -verbose
              foreach ($change in $changes.changes) { 
                  write-host $change.item.path                          
              }
        }    
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the API you're looking for is really close one of them you currently have:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/iterations/{iterationId}/changes`

The addition of the `changes` at the end gives you a list of files:
For example:

```json
{
  "changeEntries": [
    {
      "changeTrackingId": 1,
      "changeId": 1,
      "item": {
        "objectId": "e21e56d119ae81fb4ffebc4fefc6351f5b5ef888",
        "path": "/new_feature.cpp"
      },
      "changeType": "add"
    },
    {
      "changeTrackingId": 2,
      "changeId": 2,
      "item": {
        "objectId": "5ec0f71ffb8b47bd4c0117f624647963e021f3d2",
        "path": "/new_feature.h"
      },
      "changeType": "add"
    }
  ]
}
```

From there, you should be able to use the `path` to get the source code as I think you've already noted you know how.

See [Pull Request Iteration Changes - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-iteration-changes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)